# Simple file copy program with fgetc function

Tags: c

I made simple program that can copy source file and paste another defined file.

Below is my code.

```
int main(void) {
        FILE *fp_src;
        FILE *fp_dest;

        char src[100];
        char dest[100];

        fputs("source file : ", stdout);
        gets_s(src);
        fp_src = fopen(src, "rb");

        fputs("dest file : ", stdout);
        gets_s(dest);
        fp_dest = fopen(dest, "wb");


        char ch;
        //int ch;
        while ((ch = fgetc(fp_src)) != EOF) {
            fputc(ch, fp_dest);
        }

        fclose(fp_src);
        fclose(fp_dest);
        return 0;
    }
```

When I use fgetc function, it returns integer-type value because the EOF needs 4-bytes space. I know this concept, but, when I was making this program, I used the character-type for storing the returning value by mistake. And then, I ran this program, the destination file (the file that I want to copy) cannot properly create. (the file size is 0-byte) Therefore I changed the character-type into integer-type and then I found it was working fine.

As I mentioned above, I know that fgetc returns the integer-type value. However, I don't think that using character-type for fgetc wouldn't be a problem but it was a critical problem when copying file with fgetc function.

So I didn't get it why this situation happened.

Could you help me understand it more detailed?

Comment: MSDN confirms that [`gets_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b5x9wc7.aspx) needs a length argument too.  Did the code compile without warnings?  If so, you need to turn up the warning levels on your compiler — or get a better compiler.

Comment: You don't verify that the calls to `gets_s()` work; you don't verify that the calls to `fopen()` work.  You don't know that the code should be working.  And you need to use at minimum `short`, and may as well use `int` like everyone else does, to capture the return value from `fgetc()`.  Anything else is error prone at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the `getchar`-like functions are required to be able to return *every possible character PLUS an end-file indication.*

"Every possible character" is covered by the `char` type but you have to use a wider type to cover the "PLUS" bit.

In other words, your contention that "I don't think that using character-type for `fgetc` wouldn't *(sic, assuming you meant to type 'would' here)* be a problem" is dead wrong.

The prototype for `fgetc()` states quite clearly: `int fgetc ( FILE * stream );` and *that's* what you should generally be using for the return value, an `int`. Anything else is asking for trouble (though, provided you understand the implicit conversions, you could also use wider or even thinner types but `int` is probably the best choice).

And, as an aside, you should generally check the return values from every call where failure can propagate problems (such as `gets_s` or `fopen`). And ensure you pass the correct number and/or type of parameters, something a decent compiler should warn you about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. char cannot recover the EOF and getchar-like functions need to more space in order to cover plus bits. However, before end of the file, char-type can read and write the file.However, my program didnt' work when they read file for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that `gets_s()` takes two arguments, the `char *` to read into, and an `rsize_t`, the maximum number of chars to read - http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets

However, I think the root of the problem is that type `char` cannot represent `EOF`. I'd recommend using type `int` instead of `char` for your `ch` character, since `fgetc()` returns and `int` and `fputc()` takes an `int` as an argument.

Comment: `uint8_t` is no better than `char` (or `unsigned char`, or `signed char`); you must use at least a `short` and may as well use `int`.